# GIT/DIFF - Reverse patch between a moved local file and an old commit

Tags: git, diff, revert

There was a commit for a particular file, at some point that needs to be reversed

I want to create a revert patch between that old commit with hash #A1B2C3D4:

```
folderA/file.c
```

...and the file in my working folder (on main branch):

```
folderB/folderC/file.c
```

The difficulty here, for me is that the file has been moved to another directory structure

**how does one use git/diff/gittools/bc to generate such a reverse patch to a file that was moved?**

I checked the doc, but **git revert** command does not seem to do what I want

thanks for your help

[edit]

I tried

```
git diff A1B2C3D4 HEAD -- folderA/file.c folderB/folderC/file.c
```

it returned

```
Similarity index 100%
rename from folderA/file.c
rename from folderB/folderC/file.c
```

Comment: Is `A1B2C3D4` the commit that you want to revert or is there another commit between this one and `HEAD` whose change you wan to revert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could checkout `A1B2C3D4`, rename the file there to the name that you have now. Then you can compare the 2 commits that you care about to generate the patch

```
git checkout A1B2C3D4
git mv some-file some-file-new-path
git commit -m "Renamed file"
git diff the-other-commit -- some-file-new-path > some-patch-revert.patch
git diff HEAD the-other-commit -- some-file-new-path > some-patch.patch
```

Use the patch that best suits your needs.

Comment: it does not seem to aim a particular file, but the whole branch

Comment: As you can see from `similarity index 100%`, the file at the old and the new location are exactly identical between the two commits.

Comment: Ok.... here goes another attempt... let me adjust the answer.

Comment: yeah I did something similar but simpler by duplicating the whole repo, your solution is more lightweight indeed :-)

Answer (score 1):

If there is sufficient common text in the old version and the new version, Git should be able to determine that the file was renamed. Then you also receive a patch text the shows the changes with this command:

```
git diff old-commit HEAD -- folderA/file.c  folderB/folderC/file.c
```

The command instructs `git diff` to investigate the two files. Of course, one path is not present in `HEAD` the other is not present it `old-commit`. For this reason, add `--` to the command to tell `git diff`: no, really, I mean that the following two arguments are file paths (more correctly: pathspec).

Comment: I updated the question with the result of the command, it dos not generate a patch

Comment: I'll duplicate the work folder and revert to that commit, to create the diff between the two work folders. also the patch needs to be reverted